# why cant i add space before the buttons in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to add some space after the drop down but it's not working...

**PHP**

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("server","username","") or die("Error connecting to MYSQL");
mysql_select_db("database") or die("Error connecting to database");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column ASC");
"<select name='drpdwn'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo "<option value=" .$row['col1'] . ">".$row['col1'] ."</option>";
}
echo "<br/>";
echo "";
?>
<br/>
<input type="submit" id="thisSbmit" value="Delete Contact" onClick="chck()">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="cls" class="cls" value="Clear">
```

This is the code i added `<br>` two times and blank space once but it doesn't work..

[image: see this image pls]

Comment: You should post the css and the generated html as this does not seem to be related to php.

Comment: Also your `<select>` element doesn't seem to be output, neither is its closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually close the `<select>` (with a `</select>`).

```
- echo "<br/>";
+ echo "</select><br/>";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LTXrd/

vs. http://jsfiddle.net/LTXrd/1/

I do find it a bit odd that it has that effect, but I guess that's good motivation to properly format HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems I can see:

- You are not closing the `select` element
- `input` elements are inline elements so if you want to add space around them using for example css margins, you should change that to something like: `input { display: inline-block; }`